# Restrict first and last characters to be whitespace

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I want a regex to match something like `_Hello_` or `_Hell No_`

So the requirements are `_` on both sides and some text in between. However the text cannot start with or end with whitespace (they can however contain whitespace inside the text).

I have tried `_[\S]+.*[\S]+_` but this fails to match when i have less than 2 characters in the text eg `_H_`

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just treat the single-character case separately:

```
_(\S.*\S|\S)_
```

You probably want to replace `.*` with `.*?` to make it non-greedy. Otherwise, you'll fail to properly match multiple instances of this pattern in a row:

```
_foo_ _bar_
 ^^^^^^^^^
 one match
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following pattern:

```
_\S(.*\S)?_
```

This pattern allows for a single non whitespace character.  It also allows for more characters beyond this, but they must end with a non whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
_[^\s+]?.*[^\s+]_
```

Using `^` inside the brackets means NOT any whitespace.
       `?` means    zero or one of (any character that's not whitespace)
    `.*` means any    number of any characters

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following pattern:

```
^_.+_$
```

This will match the first three lines but not lines 4 and 5:

```
_Hello_
_Hello_Hello_
_Hello Hello_
 _Hello_
_Hello_ 
       ^---Trailing space here
```

Comment: This would match `__`, i.e. just two underscores, which may not be what the OP wants.